# Override Joomla mailer settings in case of using secondary mailserver as backup

Tags: emails, joomla-mail

Does anyone know how to "override" these mail settings in Joomla?

I need to set host, port etc at PHP level:

```
$mailer->setHost = "localhost";
$mailer->setPort = 25;
$mailer->setSMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->setSMTPSecure = "";
$send = $mailer->Send();
```

I use the settings as a "backup" mailserver in case the main mailserver is down but when I print out the mailer object the settings for host, port etc are NOT changed by the code above. So my code above does not have any effect.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The properties that you're using do not exist (I don't know where you're getting them from). You will need to use the function `useSmtp` in the `JMail` class in order to set the host, the port, etc... See: `libraries\joomla\mail\mail.php`.